# Using qsort for sorting a custom ADT returning a segfault in C?

Tags: c, arraylist, qsort

I've been using qsort to sort my arraylist in C (custom implementation)by character, but it returns a seg-fault & I am not quite sure why.
It seems like it is trying to access a pointer to an element that has already been removed.

Literal initialization:

```
Literal *newLiteralStruct (char *name, int i){
    Literal *this = malloc(sizeof(Literal));
    this->name = name;
    this->isNegative = i; 
    return this;
}
```

Sort function:

```
int sort(const void *struct1, const void *struct2){
    Literal* literalStruct1 = *(Literal**)struct1;
    Literal* literalStruct2 = *(Literal**)struct2;
    return strcmp(literalStruct1->name, literalStruct2->name);
}
```

Method call:

```
{
                printf("Moving onto propagation..\n");
                Literal *literal = findNextUnitLiteral(allClauses);
                appendArrayList(unitLiterals, literal);
                checkForLiteralsInClauses(literal, allClauses);

                }
            while (findNextUnitLiteral(allClauses) != NULL);
        }
        unsigned int arraySize = size(unitLiterals);
        qsort((void*)unitLiterals, arraySize, sizeof(Literal*), &sort);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size(unitLiterals); i++){
            Literal *literal = get(unitLiterals, i);
            printf("%s", literal->name);
}
```

Full function that may cause issues:

```
void checkForLiteralsInClauses(Literal *literal, arrayList *clauseArray){
    Literal *literalToCheck;
    printf("Literal being propagated: ");
    printCharacterAndSign(literal);

    unsigned int clauseArraySize = size(clauseArray);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i<clauseArraySize; i++){
            arrayList * literalArray = get(clauseArray, i);
            unsigned int literalArraySize = size(literalArray);
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < literalArraySize; j++){
                literalToCheck = get(literalArray, j);
                if (literalToCheck == NULL){
                    break;
                }

                if ((strcmp(literalToCheck->name, literal->name)==0) && literalToCheck->isNegative != literal->isNegative){
                    printf("Literal identified: ");
                    printCharacterAndSign(literalToCheck);
                    printf("This is a converse literal. The literal in the clause will now be removed.\n");
                    removeFromArrayList(literalArray, j);
                    if (size(literalArray) == 0){
                        printf("contradiction");
                        printf("-");
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                    }
                   else if (size(literalArray) == 1){
                        printf("This is now a unit literal");
                        appendArrayList(clauseArray, literalArray);  
                    }
                }
                else if ((strcmp(literalToCheck->name, literal->name)==0 && literalToCheck->isNegative == literal->isNegative)){
                    printf("Literal identified: ");
                    printCharacterAndSign(literalToCheck);
                    printf("Same literal. The full clause will now be removed.\n");
                    removeFromArrayList(literalArray, j);
                    // destroyArrayList(literalArray);
                    removeFromArrayList(clauseArray, i--);
                    if (literalToCheck == 0){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (strcmp(literalToCheck->name, literal->name) != 0){
                    printf("Literal identified: ");
                    printCharacterAndSign(literalToCheck);
                    printf("No match. Moving on!\n");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

ArrayList Implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "ArrayList.h"

#define initialCapacity 10
/*
defining a function that copies (length) number of bytes from the pointer of the source to the pointer of the destination
mainly used for removing functions
*/
#define arrayListShift(s, offset, length) memmove((s)+offset, (s), (length)*sizeof(s));

/**
creating a new arrayList as defined in arraylist.h
allocates memory for the initialCapacity of the array, as specified above
initializes the size of the array as 0, as no elements have been added
the maximum capacity at the start is the pre-defined initial capacity
*/

arrayList *createNewArrayList(){

    arrayList* arrayList = malloc(sizeof(arrayList));
    arrayList->size = 0;
    // Allocate the array
    arrayList->element = malloc(sizeof(void*) * initialCapacity);
    assert(arrayList->element);
    arrayList->maxCapacity = initialCapacity;
    return arrayList;
} 


void appendArrayList(arrayList * arrayList, void * item ) {

    if (arrayList->size == arrayList->maxCapacity){
        arrayList->element = realloc(arrayList->element, 2*arrayList->maxCapacity * sizeof(void*));
        arrayList->maxCapacity *= 1.5;
    }
    arrayList->element[arrayList->size++] = item;
}

/**
 * remove an element from the array at a specified index position
 * using memmove to shift all the following elements back by an index position
 */ 

void removeFromArrayList(arrayList *arrayList, unsigned int index){
    unsigned int size = arrayList->size;
    for (unsigned int i = index; i < (size-1); i++){
        arrayList->element[i] = arrayList->element[i+1];
    }
    arrayList->size--;
}

void removeByPointer(arrayList*arrayList, void*pointer){
    unsigned int num = arrayList->size;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<num; i++){
        if (arrayList->element[i] == pointer){
            removeFromArrayList(arrayList, i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * clear the array of all its elements
 */
void clearArrayList(arrayList*arrayList){
    arrayList->size = 0;
}

/**
 * return the size of the array
 */
unsigned int size(arrayList*arrayList){
    return arrayList->size;
}

/**
 * return the maxCap of the array
 */
unsigned int maxCapacity(arrayList*arrayList){
    return arrayList->maxCapacity;
}

void *get(arrayList* arrayList, unsigned int index)
{
    return arrayList->element[index];

}

/**
 * free all the memory being used up by the arraylist
 */
void destroyArrayList(arrayList *arrayList){
    free(arrayList->element);
    free(arrayList);
}
```

Comment: More code please, see [mcve]

Comment: Hello, I have added more code to the question, in order to make it more readable. I hope this provides more insight.

Comment: `unitLiterals` is evidently an `arrayList`. So the call should be `qsort(unitLiterals->element, arraySize, sizeof(Literal *), sort)`. The key point is that you want to sort the `element` array, not the struct itself. Also, you don't need to cast the pointer to `void *`. That's done automatically when the parameter type is `void *`. And you don't need to take the address of a function. The name by itself acts like a pointer to a function.